# Find polyline end vertex on polyline edge

Tags: arcgis-desktop, topology, vertices, flow

I am looking for a basic or best approach to find any polyline End-vertex that falls on the polyline Edge. I have a set of polyline data that shows the flow of electricity based on the Start and End vertex of each of the polylines ID.

If an end vertex of a polyline falls on the polyline edges, it will give an error to the electricity flow as to many electric sources flow within the polyline edges.

Hence I need to find the best approach to find all the end vertex of polyline that falls on the polyline edges.

[image]

Comment: Are you using ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap?  What have you tried?  Investigating the Intersect tool might be one suggestion.

Comment: Split your polylines by end points and summarize output by orig_fid. Those with frequency greater than one is your answer. This only works for 2d lines, which is unlikely in your case.

Comment: I'm using ArcMap. Currently been using Feature Vertices to Points to find the end vertex for all the polylines. Multiple counts of end vertex via Collect Events in the same coordinates indicates that the flow of electricity is wrong as it needs to flow by start-end and continue with start to the end of next polylines. So currently I'm stuck on another parameter which is end vertex cannot fall on the edge of a polyline.